# How to get the value of a node inside another node from XML Document?

Tags: xpath, liferay, liferay-6, dom4j

[**Liferay**](https://www.liferay.com/) uses **DOM4J** Parser to parse XML documents and it has an editor called *WCM Structures* that allows you to create a range of fields/nodes:

[image]

The editor generates this XML document:

```
<root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US">
    <dynamic-element fieldNamespace="ddm" indexType="keyword" localizable="true" name="Separator7562" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" type="ddm-separator">
        <!-- meta data -->
        <dynamic-element dataType="string" indexType="keyword" localizable="true" multiple="false" name="Select" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" type="select">
            <dynamic-element name="option11132" type="option" value="value 1">
                <meta-data locale="en_US">
                    <entry name="label">
                        <![CDATA[Label]]>
                    </entry>
                </meta-data>
            </dynamic-element>
            <dynamic-element name="option11133" type="option" value="value 2">
                <!-- meta data -->
            </dynamic-element>
            <dynamic-element name="option11134" type="option" value="value 3">
                <!-- meta data -->
            </dynamic-element>
        </dynamic-element>
    </dynamic-element>
</root>
```

Then by using [FreeMarker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeMarker) (a **Java**-based Template Engine) I can get all the nodes using XPath Expression by calling `document.selectNodes()` or `document.selectSingleNode()`.
My problem is that I'm not able to get the value of a node inside another node (see the XML).

```
<#if className == "com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle">
    <#assign journalArticle = assetRenderer.getArticle() />
    <#assign document = saxReaderUtil.read(journalArticle.getContentByLocale(locale.toString())) />

    <#-- retrieve fields from structure -->
    <#assign separatorNodes = document.selectNodes("/root/dynamic-element[@name='Separator7562']/dynamic-content") />

    <#list separatorNodes as node>
        <#assign selectValue = node.selectSingleNode("dynamic-element[@name='Select']").getText() />
    </#list>

    Option: ${selectValue}
</#if>
```

I get this error:

```
Expression selectValue is undefined on line 16, column 42 in 20155#20195#42611.
```

Comment: I don't see any `dynamic-content` in the sample.

Comment: @MartinHonnen When I remove `dynamic-content` I don't get any error, but I don't get even the value of selectValue (`.getText()`).

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you so much! I solved the issue. I removed `dynamic-content` from `separatorNodes` and I added it to `selectValue`. The `selectValue` returns the value of dynamic-element ("value 1") but I want to get the label `<![CDATA[Label]]>`

Comment: Please post the first comment as answer so I can mark this question as resolved.